# Can whole table be dynamically created in ejs?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, dynamic-programming

Controller looks like this:

```
'use strict';

const PostgreRepository = require('../repository/repository');
const sequelize = require('../config/database');
const models = require('../models/init-models')

models(sequelize);

class Controller {
    constructor(model) {
        this._model = model;
        this.add = this.add.bind(this);
        this.findAll = this.findAll.bind(this);
        this.findOne = this.findOne.bind(this);
        this.update = this.update.bind(this);
        this.remove = this.remove.bind(this);
        this.repo = new PostgreRepository(sequelize, this._model)
    }

    add(req, res) {
        console.log(req.originalUrl);
        this.repo.add(req.body).then(data =>{
            res.send(data)
        }, err => res.status(400).send(err))
    }

    findAll(req, res) {
        this.repo.findAll().then(data => {
            res.send(data)
            // res.render('pages/index', {data:data})
        }, err => res.status(400).send(err))

    }

    findOne(req, res) {
        this.repo.findOne(req.params.id).then(data => {
            res.send(data)
        }, err => res.status(400).send(err))
    }

    update(req, res) {
        this.repo.update(req.body, req.params.id).then(data => {
            res.send(data)
        }, err => res.status(400).send(err))
    }

    remove(req, res) {
        console.log(req.params.id);
        this.repo.remove(req.params.id).then(data => {
            res.send(data)
        }, err => res.status(400).send(err))
    }
}

module.exports = Controller
```

I have APIs that return JSON list of objects that differ in number of columns.

Can I create single EJS page that would generate table based on the number of columns received?

For example, one JSON would return:

```
[
    {
        "country_pk": 1,
        "code": "AF",
        "name": "Afghanistan"
    },
    {
        "country_pk": 2,
        "code": "AL",
        "name": "Albania"
    },
    {
        "country_pk": 3,
        "code": "DZ",
        "name": "Algeria"
    }, ...
]
```

and another would have:

```
[ {
        "city_pk": 1041,
        "city": "Partesh",
        "lat": "42.4019",
        "lng": "21.4336",
        "admin_name": "Partesh",
        "capital": "admin",
        "population": "5300",
        "population_proper": "5300",
        "country": 247
    },
    {
        "city_pk": 1042,
        "city": "Korishë",
        "lat": "42.2576",
        "lng": "20.7981",
        "admin_name": "Prizren",
        "capital": "",
        "population": "5279",
        "population_proper": "5279",
        "country": 247
    }, ...
]
```

So, can I use EJS to dynamically create table depending on the JSON received? A link or example would be great, but explanation is preferred!

I know how to iterate over an array, but only if I know the names of the field (columns), like this:

```
<% for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){ %>
<h1><%= data[i].code %></h1>
<h3><%= data[i].name %></h3>
<% } %>
```

but do not know how to do it if I have no information on the number or names of the fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can iterate over the array like you said, then iterate over each object of the array twice. First to print the headers, then to print the data

> The for...of statement creates a loop iterating over iterable objects, including: built-in String, Array, array-like objects (e.g., arguments or NodeList), TypedArray, Map, Set, and user-defined iterables. It invokes a custom iteration hook with statements to be executed for the value of each distinct property of the object.
>
> The for...in statement iterates over all enumerable properties of an object that are keyed by strings

```
<table>
 <% for(const obj of data){ %>
  <tr>
   <% for(const key in obj) { %>
    <th><%= key %></th>
   <% } %>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <% for(const key in obj) { %>
   <td><%= obj[key] %></td>
  <% } %>
  </tr>
 <% } %> 
</table>
```

Comment: You are a life savior!